# Zend Studio 9 - Create PHP Project From Git (BitBucket)

Tags: zend-studio, bitbucket

I can not for the life of me get Zend Studio to create a project from git (bit bucket)

I have tried HTTPS, SSH

I have generated a key and put it in bit bucket, I have the key configured in Zend, I am not sure what else I can try, I am dying for simple step by step instructions to get this project created

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out I needed Putty's Pageant.exe running with the key imported.